# How to divide number_field into 3 parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

In the model, I have an integer field for phone. In the view is this field displayed like this:

```
<%= f.number_field :phone %>
```

I am trying to display this one input for phone number as 3 inputs, I want to offer to user in the view something like this:

```
___ - ___ - ____
```

Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: what's the length of the number?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin offers this functionality within one input field:

> It allows a user to more easily enter fixed width input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format (dates,phone numbers, etc).

The demo page includes a phone format example: `(___) ___-____`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create 3 fields in view and let the user enter the number in 3 separate parts. In view it would look something like this

```
<p><%= f.number_field_tag "area_code" %> - 
<%= f.number_field_tag "phone1" %> - 
<%= f.number_field_tag "phone2" %> </p>
```

In controller you will join these 3 into 1 string to be able to save it according to your model setup

```
def create_user
...
@user = User.new
@user.phone_number = params[:area_code].to_s + params[:phone1].to_s + params[:phone2].to_s
...
end
```

I would also recommend saving the phone number as string in model to avoid incorrect storage of numbers that start with 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work me, because I am getting error about **undefined method `phone1' for ...** etc...

Comment: I have edited the code above, should be working now, please try and share results